# how to change a dynamic sql query of a stored procedure to static sql query in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'Create Table '||vCUPRSBaseTableName
  ||' As Select * From '||vCUPRSTableName
  ||' where C_DESTINATION_ENTITY='''||l_bc_a(i)
  ||''' and LATEST=1'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's very rare that you have to create a table like this in Oracle. If you explain the rationale then maybe there's a better approach that can be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have static sql with a table name bound to a variable. The only way to do this is with dynamic sql

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to execute DDL in stored procedures.    Combined with the fact that you want flexibility in naming both the target and source tables, dynamic SQL is your only option.

However, as David A observes, it is actually pretty rare to have to create tables in this fashion.  If you were to explain your use case we should be able to propose a better approach.  If I were a betting man I would place money on temporary tables as the solution you really want.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#sthref183).